# Svg filter get outline of two blurred Objects

Tags: svg, filter, merge, svg-filters

[image]

I have Two squares.

The end goal is to get the rounded outline of two merged svg objects. So, to achieve this, I first blurred them, with

```
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
```

[image]

Then, I multiplied the opacity by 30 and subtracted 255*-9, increasing the contrast and merging the two shapes

```
<feColorMatrix
  in="blur"
  type="matrix"
  values="
        1 0 0 0 0
        0 1 0 0 0 
        0 0 1 0 0  
        0 0 0 30 -9"
  result="goo"
/>
```

[image]

But the result I want is not this. I want to get the outline of this shape. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What output do you really want? Do you want the path coords like @RobertLongson seems to assume? Do you just want to produce the graphic representation of that "outline"? And if so, what's this "outline" exactly? Like a "stroke" around the produced shape (e.g https://jsfiddle.net/ek2sqcb4/) or the difference between the original rects and the gooey effect you produced (https://jsfiddle.net/ek2sqcb4/1/)  or something entirely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just the outline, add a feMorphology/dilate and a composite/out to your filter.

(If you want the original squares subtracted from the goo, then omit the feMorphology and change "goo" to SourceGraphic in the feComposite/out.)

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewBox=" 0 0 400 400">
<defs>
  <filter id="outline" x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="200%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
  values="
        1 0 0 0 0
        0 1 0 0 0 
        0 0 1 0 0  
        0 0 0 30 -9" result="goo"/>
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
    <feComposite operator="out" in2="goo"/>
/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#outline)">
  
  <rect fill="red" x="10" y="30" width="100" height="100"/>
  
    <rect fill="red" x="120" y="30" width="100" height="100"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```